# How to make upright bars using geom_bar with negative y values?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, negative-number, yaxis

I am trying to make the following bar plot using ggplot (if base r is simpler that is okay, I am just more familiar with ggplot):
[image: GoalPlot]

This seems simple to me but for some reason, no matter what I try it is not working.

My df:

```
structure(list(Target_depth_mean1 = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22), TS_mean1 = c(-47, 
-45, -40, -43, -40, -39, -42, -42, -37, -41, -41, -38, -40, -41, 
-41, -40, -42, -42, -41, -38)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have tried the following:

```
ggplot(STmean, aes(x=Target_depth_mean1, y=TS_mean1)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") #almost what I want but I don't want the bars upside down, also tried geom_col instead but still upside down bars
```

and...

```
ggplot(STmean, aes(x=Target_depth_mean1, y=TS_mean1)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") +
  ylim(-48,-36) #doesn't plot anything
```

and...

```
ggplot(STmean, aes(x=Target_depth_mean1, y=TS_mean1)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-50,-30)) #still upside down bars
```

and...

```
ggplot(STmean, aes(x=Target_depth_mean1, y=TS_mean1)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_y_reverse() #plots upright but I need the values reversed too (smaller on bottom)
```

and...

```
ggplot(STmean, aes(x=Target_depth_mean1, y=TS_mean1)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_y_reverse(limits=c(-50,-30)) #doesn't plot anything
```

and...
library(scales)

```
ggplot(STmean, aes(x=Target_depth_mean1, y=TS_mean1)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-50, -30), oob= rescale_none) #still upside down, and if I switch to limits = c(-30,-50) plots upright but again need smaller values (-50) on bottom of y axis...
```

and...

```
ggplot(STmean, aes(x=Target_depth_mean1, y=TS_mean1)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = range(STmean$TS_mean1)) #upside down!
```

I also tried making TS values positive and adding the negative symbol after...

```
STmean1 <- STmean %>%
  mutate(across(c("TS_mean1"), abs))
```

trying to plot this...

```
ggplot(STmean1, aes(x=Target_depth_mean1, y=TS_mean1)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(50, 30), 
                     oob= rescale_none,
                     labels=function(x) paste0("-",x)) #upside down
```

What am I doing wrong? I feel like I am so close but can't get it to work. I've been trying for hours and looked at other SO questions, but no luck... Tried the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64972802/r-ggplot-reverse-y-axes-and-draw-bars-from-bottom) question, but didn't work.

Comment: here an idea

`ggplot(STmean, aes(x=Target_depth_mean1, y=-TS_mean1)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = range(-STmean$TS_mean1)) `

Comment: almost, but that is still putting the 37 on the bottom of the y axis (47 at top) and I need that reversed..any suggestions on how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34104967/r-ggplot-bar-graph-with-baseline-that-doesnt-start-at-zero), you can do the following:

```
ggplot(STmean, aes(x=Target_depth_mean1, y=TS_mean1 - min(TS_mean1))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(from = min(STmean$TS_mean1),
                                  to = max(STmean$TS_mean1), by = 1) - min(STmean$TS_mean1),
                     labels = seq(from = min(STmean$TS_mean1),
                                  to = max(STmean$TS_mean1), by = 1)) + 
  ylab("TS_mean1")
```

Comment: perfect! Thank you so much!! didn't think about playing with the breaks argument...